# Inserting arraylist values into the sql server database using java

Tags: java, android, sql-server, arraylist

I am fairly new to android programming and I have faced a small problem. I have an arraylist consisting of names of person selected from a multi-select listview, the problem is that Whenever I insert those arraylist values into the database, It inserts it as one string:
[Database row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4M56.png). How do i iterate thru an arraylist and at the same time insert its values into the database?

here is my code:

```
try {
 Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
  if (con == null) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECTION FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else {

  String samp = "";
  String names = "";
  samp = myArrayAdapter.getCheckedItems().toString();
  ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  data1.add(samp);

  for(int x=0; x<data1.size(); x++)
   {
      names += String.valueOf(data1.get(x));
      String query = "INSERT INTO AUTOINC(PersonName)"+"VALUES('"+names+"')";
      PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

   }
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INSERT SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INSERT FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", ex);
   }
```

Thank you for any future replies.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `names += String.valueOf(data1.get(x))` ? The plus sign on this line will concatenate one name each iteration and on the last iteration it will add a new line with all names concatenated.

Comment: Thank You Mr. @Trunst, for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with that?

```
List<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(samp.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")));

for (String name : data1) {
  names += name;   // This lines concatenate the name.
 //If you want to insert single name the you can directly insert the name value into databas.  
  String query = "INSERT INTO AUTOINC(PersonName)"+"VALUES('"+name+"')";
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement =   con.prepareStatement(query);
  preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: It works sir, thank you. But whenever I insert it there are always braces involved [] at the start and end of the insertion process.

Comment: Check my update answer that will solve your problem.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty do you know how to implement a JsonArrayRequest using the google's volley lib? please check this question I hope you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995091/how-to-implement-jsonarrayrequest-using-googles-volley-lib

Answer (score 0):

look at this code...

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
                    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
                    pi.setName("UserName");
                    pi.setValue(txtName.getText().toString());
                    pi.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi);
                    pi=new PropertyInfo();
                    pi.setName("UserAge");
                    pi.setValue(txtVal.getText().toString());
                    pi.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi);


SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(webRequest);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
    Log.d("CheckLogin-SOAP ACTION", SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    Log.d("CheckLogin - Response", response.toString());

    status= Boolean.valueOf(response.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback sir, but I am new to android programming and can not comprehend much of your code.